# Expression Blend not showing Create Binding Window, Invisible?

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

This has just started happening and occurs in all my projects when using Expression Blend.

It I click on any item in a page, lets say a ListBox, and then I want to bind to a property, lets say the ItemsSource, I do so by clicking the small box next to ItemsSource which gives you a menu of `Custom Expression`, `Reset`, `Convert To Local value` etc etc

When I select `Create Data Binding...` I don't get the Binding Window popup. If I try click anywhere with the mouse then I get the typical Windows sound when you try clicking away from a window that needs your attention. So to me it seems the window is there but its not showing. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever happen to solve this?

Comment: No I think I ended up reinstalling visual studio and blend